# VHDL: Select module architecture using parametric name

Tags: vhdl

I am aware that I can instantiate one architecture or another with

```
Module_inst : entity work.Module(rtl_1)
```

where `rtl_1` is the literal name of the desired architecture.

My question is: is there a syntax that allows the use of a constant inside the parenthesis to choose the architecture?
Something like:

```
constant MY_ARCH : string := "rtl_1";
Module_inst : entity work.Module(MY_ARCH)
```

so that I can change multiple modules at once.

Comment: IEEE Std 1076-2008 11.7 Component instantiation 11.7.1 General "instantiated_unit ::= ... entity *entity*_name [ ( *architecture*_identifier ) ]". No. "if an architecture identifier appears in the instantiated unit, then that identifier shall be the same as the simple name of an architecture body associated with the entity declaration denoted by the corresponding entity name." Consider using instantiations within conditionally controlled generate statements.

Answer (score 0):

You can instantiate different entities and architectures from a `configuration`.

The `architecture`'s declarative part would define a `component`, the architecture body would then instantiate this (without the `entity` keyword), and the configuration would map the component to an entity.

It's a lot to type, though. If you want an example, I'm using configurations to run the same testbench in four different setups in [this project](https://github.com/Backseating-Committee-2k/vhdl/tree/main/logic/cpu). The `tb_cpu.vhdl` contains the main testbench code, the four other files whose names start with `tb_cpu` provide configurations to switch between two different implementations of the CPU itself, and of the register file inside.

The important thing to know is that if you use a configuration, you need to give its name as the toplevel for elaboration, instead of the toplevel component's entity name. Whether you use different entities or different architectures here is up to you, and you can also optionally specify a `generic map` and a `port map` if the `component` and the `entity` do not fit exactly.

Comment: While FPGA vendors support configuration specifications as block declarative items in an architecture declarative part for synthesis they don't support configuration declarations for synthesis. A configuration specification by itself provides no useful ability to specify an architecture by indirection. Your vhdl/logic/cpu other files provide configuration declarations all specifying architecture sim of tb_cpu which isn't the top of a synthesis eligible design (where in cpu_sequential.vhdl and cpu_pipelined.vhdl you have architectures rtl).

Comment: @user16145658 you can specify the architecture in the `use entity ...` lines in parentheses.

Comment: These configurations all apply to the same toplevel, but they change out entities inside.